# HTML label with different behaviour on Safari

Tags: css, html, label

I have a checkbox and a label for it, and within a label there is an input box. When I write something in input box, I don't expect checkbox to toggle (enable/disable). On Chrome and Firefox it works fine, but on Safari selecting input within label also toggles the checkbox.
How can I prevent this from happening?

Here is my code:

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" id="xyz">
 <label for="xyz">
  <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty">This is my label for xyz checkbox, Click on Qty should not enable/disable the checkbox
 </label>
</div>
```

Comment: It took a few revisions - sorry - check out my latest answer and next steps to try.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is probably to move `<input type="number">` outside `<label>`.

Example:

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" id="xyz">
  <p>
   <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty">
   <label for="xyz">
      This is my label for xyz checkbox, Click on Qty should not enable/disable the checkbox
   </label>
  </p>
</div>
```

Remember that all form elements should have a corresponding label.

Read more about labels:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label

Comment: yes I know it will work if I place it outside the label tag, I'm trying to understand why it's working in all the other browsers and not Safari

Comment: According to the [HTML specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html50/forms.html#the-label-element), no other labelable elements than the element's labeled control kan be a descendant of label. Unfortunately, your example contains illegal markup. It is not described in the specification what the correct browser behavior is.

Comment: This is the correct answer. Check in chrome dev tools and if my calculations are correct, chrome will have automatically adjusted the illegal markup (making the label input come out of the label), thus it works as expected because the html has been corrected to do so.

Answer (score -1):

I suspect malformed HTML that is being fixed by Chrome/Firefox for you, but not fixed correctly in Safari. You should inspect the div in the debugger in each browser and see what each DOM gives you to be sure.

You have:

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" id="xyz">
 <label for="xyz">
  <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty">This is my label for xyz checkbox, Click on Qty should not enable/disable the checkbox
 </label>   
</div>
```

You could do this instead with the same intent:

```
<div>
 <input type="checkbox" name="xyz" id="xyz">
 <label for="xyz">
  This is my label for xyz checkbox
  <input type="number" name="qty" id="qty"/>
 </label>   
</div>
```

Comment: just tried it, checkbox still get checked when I click on input qty (on safari)